# flex simple rollover problem

Tags: apache-flex, flex3, flex4

I have a panel2 inside panel1.
When I rollover panel1, I want panel2 to be visible and when mouseOut, panel2 to be invisible.
This is simple with mouseOcer and MouseOut events

Of course trouble is when I rollover panel2 (inside panel1): it starts blinking.
My question is: how to simply correct it ? (of course I would like buttons inside panel2 to be active as well)

regards

Answer (score 0):

Why this code won't work for you?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application minHeight="600" minWidth="955" xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
    xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark">
    <fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        [Bindable]
        private var isOver:Boolean;
    ]]>
    </fx:Script>
    <s:Panel horizontalCenter="0" id="panel1" mouseOut="isOver = false" mouseOver="isOver = true" title="Panel1"
        verticalCenter="0">
        <s:Panel bottom="10" id="panel2" left="10" right="10" title="Panel2" top="10" visible="{isOver}">
            <s:layout>
                <s:VerticalLayout horizontalAlign="center" paddingBottom="10" paddingLeft="10" paddingRight="10"
                    paddingTop="10" verticalAlign="middle" />
            </s:layout>
            <s:Label id="actionResult" />
            <s:HGroup>
                <s:Button click="actionResult.text = 'Button 1 clicked'" label="Button1" />
                <s:Button click="actionResult.text = 'Button 2 clicked'" label="Button2" />
            </s:HGroup>
        </s:Panel>
    </s:Panel>
</s:Application>
```